# Unable to use pickAFile in TigerJython

Tags: jython, jes

In JES, I am able to use:

```
file=pickAFile()
```

In TigerJython, however, I get the following error

```
NameError: name 'pickAFile' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong at all.  The thing is that `pickAFile()` is not a standard function in Python.  It is actually rather a function that *JES* has added for convenience, but which you probably will not find it in any other environment.

Since *TigerJython* and *JES* are both based on Jython, you can easily write a `pickAFile()` function on your own that uses Java's Swing.  Here is a possible simple implementation (the `pickAFile()` found in JES might be a bit more complex, but this should get you started):

```py
def pickAFile():
    from javax.swing import JFileChooser
    fc = JFileChooser()
    retVal = fc.showOpenDialog(None)
    if retVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
        return fc.getSelectedFile()
    else:
        return None
```

Given that it is certainly a useful function, we might have to consider including it into our next update of TigerJython.

P.S. I would like to apologise for answering so late, I have just joined SO recently and was not aware of your question (I am one of the original authors of TigerJython).

Comment: No worries at all. Appreciate the response. Thanks!